# Snowpack cannot import JavaScript from node_modules

Tags: javascript, impress.js, snowpack

I'm currently using Snowpack to build/prepare an application. I'm trying to import a JavaScript library I installed as part of the `dependencies` (block) in the `package.json` file, but somehow Snowpack is not picking up the library.

This is (an excerpt with the relevant content of) the `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "snowpack build",
    "preview": "snowpack dev"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "impress.js": "1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "snowpack": "3.3.7"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  }
}
```

The `snowpack.config.js` only contains these lines:

```js
/** @type {import("snowpack").SnowpackUserConfig } */
export default {
  devOptions: {
    open: "none",
  },
  mount: {
    src: {
      url: "/",
    },
  },
};
```

I was expecting Snowpack to bundle the `impress.js` library with this HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="node_modules/impress.js/js/impress.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/global.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to configure Snowpack for such things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case somebody come across something similar to this, the way I found to bundle `Impress.js` (and probably any other library that has/hasn't been modularized) is to just `import` it in the JavaScript file (notice the `type="module"` in the HTML `script` tag):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="scripts/global.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
import "impress.js";

impress(); // ...bootstraps/initializes Impress.js
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to convert the Impress module to ESM have you considered trying [esinstall](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esinstall)?

i.e.

convert.mjs:

```
import {install} from 'esinstall';
await install(['impress.js'], {});
```

```
node convert.mjs
```

and then in your HTML file:

```
 <script src="web_modules/impress.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was actually expecting Snowpack to be able to do such things behind scenes when certain hints (`type="module"`) are provided.